# How to make Navigation bar size constant in Angular 2?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

[image]The size of navigation bar in app component keeps changing when different components are loaded. I want to make this constant.

```
.navbar{
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
  }

  h3{
      padding-left: 43%
  }

**app.component.html**
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <h3>MY Heading</h3>
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
     </nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

On Router change based on the component loaded navigation bar adjusts its size and the "My Heading" shrinks in size and appears in two different lines instead of a single line.

I tried using fixed property in the Css of Nav Class , it did not work.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting max-height style as constant

```
.navbar{
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
  }
```

Comment: I did not understand , I used the same max-height.

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu so did it work? or you need more help?

Comment: No , Actually this time navigation bar remains 50% like defined but the heading still splits into two lines

Comment: Are you available in TeamViewer?

Comment: Reach me in fb @ aravind2109